What should the direction of arrows be in a dataflow diagram?
What should the direction of arrows be in a dataflow diagram? Should a request for data be bi-directional to show the direction of the request itself?
For example if a system 1 requests data from system 2, I understand that the primary data flow is from system 2 to system 1. But does one has to show that the request was made from system 1 with a bi-directional arrow? Or would that be misleading?
Or maybe just have the direction from system 2 to system 1 and describe on the arrow that its a "get / read data".
I have seen both types of usage, single direction and bi-direction. But would like to know what is the right thing to do? I feel single direction for request makes more sense to show who is sending data to whom, irrespective of who is initiating the request.
